# Emacs: Get user input when using interactive Python with `getpass`

Tags: python, microsoft-windows, passwords

I am, unfortunately, using Windows 7 and am running `GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2017-09-26`. Everything functions as expected from the command line.  However, within Emacs, I encounter a problem.

I have started Emacs using `-q`.  I start an interactive Python session with `M-x run-python`.  Regular input works fine.  However, when I try to use `getpass`, no input is accepted and all text is printed to the screen.  Pressing `Enter` only inserts a new line.  To demonstrate:

[image]

Text transcript of Emacs input:

```
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python.el: native completion setup failed
>>> user = input('Username: ')
Username: bob
>>> import getpass
>>> pw = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
my secret password
wait, why is it printing to screen?
and why does pressing return only insert a new line?
I can't seem to get out of this!
I'm going to press C-c C-c now  C-c C-c  C-c C-cTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\getpass.py", line 110, in win_getpass
    raise KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    my secret password
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    wait, why is it printing to screen?
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    and why does pressing return only insert a new line?
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    I can't seem to get out of this!
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I'm not sure what to do next in fixing this.

1. Does anyone else have this issue?
2. If so, might it be a problem with `python.el` and a bug report need to be submitted?  And where would that bug be reported?
3. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make [jpkotta's solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/37862/5296) work for Windows, you need to use

```py
def my_getpass(prompt):
    if os.isatty(0):
        return getpass.getpass(prompt)
    else:
        return input(prompt)
```

This is because [`getpass`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/getpass.py#L97) uses `msvcrt.putwch` and `msvcrt.getwch` which only work in a `cmd.exe` console.  IMO, this is a bug in the Python libraries, they should be using the `fallback_getpass` when `os.isatty(0)` is false.

Comment: This still prints the password to the screen, but the input is accepted.  Accepting input is the primary issue and masking against over-the-shoulder attacks is secondary (and probably best suited for a separate question).

Comment: @LoremIpsum If you apply jpkotta's solution as well, then the password should not be printed (assuming the prompt matches `comint-password-prompt-regexp`, that is).

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, it works just like `input()` (terminates with `RET`, input is visible).  `getpass` relies on setting the terminal correctly, and inferior python mode isn't a standard terminal.  For example, if you do `M-x term RET python RET`, you get python running in an actual terminal and it works.  If you run python from eshell or shell (also not real terminals) it actually asks for a password in the minibuffer, but only if you have the standard prompt of "Password: ", which gives a hint that those modes are looking for "Password: " and treating it specially.  The trick is to add a filter for that, and fortunately it's all implemented already.

```
(defun jpk/inferior-python-mode-hook ()
  (add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions
            #'comint-watch-for-password-prompt
            nil 'local))
(add-hook 'inferior-python-mode-hook #'jpk/inferior-python-mode-hook)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, I did not have any success using your hook.  It appears as though Emacs has problems with terminals when running on Windows.  While `shell`, `eshell`, and `(make-comint "cmd" "cmd" nil)` all function to navigate the file system (`term` appears not to work on Windows altogether), none of them are able to run the interactive Python shell.  Each fails to accept input (similar to the screen shot) when the `python` command is issued.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're wondering how to

> apply jpkotta's solution as well

on Windows to prevent the password from being printed: you can either customize `comint-password-prompt-regexp` or just use

> the standard prompt of "Password: "

```
def my_getpass(prompt):
    if os.isatty(0):
        return getpass.getpass(prompt)
    else:
        return input('Password: ')
```

As for

> If so, might it be a problem with python.el and a bug report need to be submitted? And where would that bug be reported?

As mentioned, seems like a missing feature in python's getpass. Go for it :-) .